# How to divide all values in a pivot table column by a constant

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I would like to scale (divide, multiply) a pivot tables value by some constant that I add into the pivot tables sheet, like so:

[image]

The problem of automatically updating the pivot tables values as the values in the original data change I already solved with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

I have tried simply doing it inside a worksheet_change() method, but this gives type mismatch error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C4:C5"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Target.Value = Target.Value * Range("B1").Value <-- gives error of type mismatch
        MsgBox VarType(Target.Value)
        MsgBox VarType(Range("B1").Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Berntavicius I had to do that once in a project. What I did was to link cells (thanks to cell formulas)  from another sheet to the pivot table values and then manipulate those cells. I know it is basic but it worked well. I hope I was clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) It is clear! Would be also interesting to see how to do dynamic recalculation in VBA

Comment: You could just use a calculated field in your Pivot, with some code you could alter the (calculated-field) formula when necessary

Comment: Thanks @EvR I was considering that and consider this to be a good suggestion. Unfortunately this adds another field into the pivot table and I was asked to do it transparently. Also, it would be great to know many possible solutions/workarounds for the problem, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. When the event `WorkSheet_Change` fires, check if your scaling value (in `B1`) has changed. If so, re-write the calculated field:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables(1).CalculatedFields("ScaledField"). _
        StandardFormula = "=Kaina*" & Range("B1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll need to create a calculated field called `ScaledField` (or give it your own name - just change the code too) **and** you might want to change the formula if you don't want to scale `[Kaina]`, but something else.

PS. If the value isn't `[Kaina]`, but  `[Kaina Sausis]` then the formula would require single quotes to wrap the field name:

```
StandardFormula = "='Kaina Sausis'*" & Range("B1").Value
```

Comment: Some posts say that it is impossible to manipulate the pivot table data directly (VBA or non VBA). Maybe you know if that is true? I'm starting to think so after not finding and answer after quite an extensive search.

Comment: I tested the above before posting. It works on my sample pivot. You can't modify the Pivot *output*, but you can modify the source data (but you then need to tell the pivot to refresh) and (as my example shows) you can modify the Calculated field formula - which does cause an instant refresh to the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

**Manipulating the value of data fields directly in the pivot table is not possible** (try to manually change a value or with VBA and you get an error message).

It's possible to overwrite values of row fields, but that's a bit strange (they will stay like this after and not update anymore unless you by coincidence entered a valid value).

**For calculations you can add a calculated field**. If the value is constant and the value doesn't need to be taken from a Range just add a calculated field manually (Analyze > Fields ... > Calculated Field...) and enter the constant value in the formula.

Unfortunately calculated fields cannot reference ranges so if you **really have to use the value from a Range in the formula of the calculated field you can use this VBA code** (it adds a calculated field or updates the formula if the field already exists, that would be of use if the value is not constant):

```
' You prolly have to call this only once as you are using a constant value.
' If not add to your worksheet change event
' Modify hardcoded values if needed
Sub createOrUpdateField()
    Dim fldFormula As String

    ' Construct the formula to use
    fldFormula = "= Kaina Sausis / " & ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value2

    addOrUpdateCalculatedField _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1), _
        "Kaina Sausis Calc", fldFormula, "0.00"
End Sub

' In case you want to remove the calculated field use this
' Or use the interface (Analyze > Fields ... > Calculated Field...)
Sub deleteField()
    pt.PivotFields("Kaina Sausis Calc").Delete
End Sub

' Add a calculated field to pivot table or update formula if it already exists.
' Args:
'   pt (PivotTable): The pivot table object
'   fldName (String): Name to use for the field
'   fldFormula (String): Formula to use for calculation
'   fldFormat (String): Number format to use
Sub addOrUpdateCalculatedField(pt As PivotTable, fldname As String, _
fldFormula As String, fldFormat As String)
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim ptfld As PivotField

    ' Try to reference the field to check if it already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ptfld = pt.PivotFields(fldname)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ptfld Is Nothing Then
        ' Field doesn't exist, add it
        Set ptfld = pt.CalculatedFields.Add(name:=fldname, formula:=fldFormula)
        With ptfld
            .Caption = fldname
            .NumberFormat = fldFormat
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
        End With
    Else
        ' Field already exists, change the formula only
        ptfld.StandardFormula = fldFormula
    End If

    Set wks = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set ptfld = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to find whether it is possible to manipulate Pivot table data directly using VBA in google and some books. Could not find it. Maybe you have some references for that? I tend to also think now that this is not possible since I could not find how to do it after extensive search.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius updated my answer, am 100% sure that you can't manipulate data field values. Found no documentation, but trying to change the value manually or with code shows a clear error message that it's not possible.